# Finding item in subdocument with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am trying to search for the current item:

[image: Image of mongoDB compass with email highlighted]

I tried the following: `{participants: {userEmail: 'test@gmail.com'}}`

But it did not return anything.
Im mongoDB compass i get the following in my query history:
[image: Image of mongoDB query history]

How would i write the query to find the highlighted email address? Or the document holding that email address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query expects that participants is exactly an object like:

```
{userEmail: 'test@gmail.com'}
```

What you're trying to do can be achieved with [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents):

```
{ 'participants.userEmail': 'test@gmail.com'}}
```